# Issue with HttpClient.GetStringAsync method in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

```
private async void refresh_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    httpclient.CancelPendingRequests();
    string url = "http://gensav.altervista.org/";
    var source = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url); //PROBLEM
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
    HtmlDocument result = new HtmlDocument();
    result.LoadHtml(source);

    List<HtmlNode> toftitle = result.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
                                (x => (x.Attributes["style"] != null
                                       && x.Attributes["style"].Value.Contains("font-size:14px;line-height:20px;margin-bottom:10px;"))).ToList();

    var li = toftitle[0].InnerHtml.Replace("<br>", "\n");
    li = li.Replace("<span style=\"text-transform: uppercase\">", "");
    li = li.Replace("</span>", "");
    postTextBlock.Text = li;
}
```

What this code does is basically retrieve a string from a website (HTML source which is parsed right after). This code is executed whenever i click a button: the first time i click it it works correctly, but the second time i think that the method (GetStringAsync) returns an uncompleted task and then execution continues using the old value of **source**. Indeed, my TextBlock does not update.

Any solution?

Comment: *i think that the method (GetStringAsync) returns an uncompleted task* That is highly unlikely. Are you sure you debugged correctly? How are you calling this code?

Comment: I'm calling it inside the event handler for the "Tapped" event

Comment: Could you add that code?

Comment: Have you tried executing this code without `httpclient.CancelPendingRequests()`? Also, it seems that you're always querying the same source site, are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah i tried, nothing changes. And yes, i want to query the same site because it always generates a different string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get probably a cached response.

May this will work for you:

```
httpclient.CancelPendingRequests();

// disable caching
httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

string url = "http://gensav.altervista.org/";
var source = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url);
...
```

You can also add a meaningless value to your url like this:

```cs
 string url = "http://gensav.altervista.org/" + "?nocahce=" + Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: you misspelled "nocache" in your string literal.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Http responses from getting cached, I do this (in WP8.1):

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior =
            Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior =
            Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

_httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
```

Initialize your HttpClient in this manner to prevent caching behaviour.